# Prove that $\mathrm{cosec}^2A\cdot\mathrm{sec}^2A=\tan^2A+\cot^2A+2$.

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $\mathrm{cosec}^2A\cdot\mathrm{sec}^2A=\tan^2A+\cot^2A+2$.

My attempt is as follows:

Taking LHS:

$$(1+\cot^2A)(1+\cot^2A)$$
$$\left(1+\cot^2A\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{\tan^2A}\right)$$
$$(1+\cot^2A)\left(\frac{1+\tan^2A}{\tan^2A}\right)$$
$$\frac{1+\tan^2A+\cot^2A+\cot^2A.\tan^2A}{\tan^2A}$$
$$\frac{2+\tan^2A+\cot^2A}{\tan^2A}$$

So my answer is having $\tan^2A$ extra in the denominator.
Is the question wrong or I am missing something?

Comment: I believe the question is wrong as it is clearly not satisfied for $A = \frac{\pi}4$

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit I think that's a typo.  I made an edit, but not sure when it will show up.  The one of the cosecants has to be a secant.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your second $\csc^2A$ was meant to be $\sec^2A$, viz.$$\tan^2A+\cot^2A+2=(\tan A+\cot A)^2=\left(\frac{\sin^2A+\cos^2A}{\sin A\cos A}\right)^2\\=\frac{1}{\sin^2A\cos^2A}=\csc^2A\sec^2A.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $s=\sin A$ and $c=\cos A$.  Then $\tan A=s/c$ and $\cot A=c/s$.  Therefore
$$\text{RHS}=\tan^2A+\cot^2A +2=\left(\frac{s}{c}\right)^2+\left(\frac{c}{s}\right)^2+2.$$
This gives
$$\text{RHS}=\frac{s^4+c^4+2s^2c^2}{s^2c^2}=\frac{(s^2+c^2)^2}{s^2c^2}.$$
But $s^2+c^2=\sin^2A+\cos^2A=1$.  Therefore
$$\text{RHS}=\frac{1}{s^2c^2}=\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)^2.$$
Since $\operatorname{cosec} A=1/s$ and $\sec A=1/c$, the claim follows (presumably you wanted to prove $\operatorname{cosec}^2A\sec^2A=\tan^2A+\cot^2A+2$).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the very first line. You should instead have $$\csc^2A\sec^2A=(1+\cot^2)(1+\tan^2A).$$

Answer (score 0):

No the problem is correct which can be established in many ways:

One of them

$$\csc^2A\sec^2A=\dfrac1{\sin^2A\cos^2A}=\dfrac{\sin^2A+\cos^2A}{\sin^2A\cos^2A}=\sec^2A+\csc^2A=?$$

Or where you have left off,

$$\dfrac{(\tan A+1)^2}{\tan^2A}=\cdots=\left(\tan A+\cot A\right)^2=?$$